# 2D animation tool with free-form deformations

Tags: images, software-recommendation, animation

Basically, I'm looking for something that provides the 2D animation capabilities of Spriter (the support for bone rigs, in particular) but also comes with the deformation capabilities of Photoshop's Puppet Warp (e.g. I want to be able to take a ball, punch it and deform it on impact).

Is there such a thing? I'm adamant there must be, but I cannot seem to find anything useful.

Comment: [Toon Boom Harmony](https://www.toonboom.com/products/harmony)? Incidentally all 3d animation tools are also 2d animation tools.

Comment: Also all bone systems allow for free form deformations ;)

Answer (score -3):

You are looking for a software called "Spine" !

Comment: In particular, it looks like you would need the Professional edition to get access to the free-form deformation tool. https://esotericsoftware.com/spine-purchase

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.